# Tool for periodic mirroring of full data-set from GraphQL endpoint?

Tags: graphql, extract, etl, data-mining

I'm looking for a tool that can make a clone of data exposed on a GraphQL API.

Basically something that can run periodically and recurively copy the raw data reponse to disk, making use of connection based pagination & cursors to ensure consistency of progress of the mirrored content.

Assuming this would be a runner that extracts data 24/7, it will either have to rewrite/transform already copied data, or even better apply updates in a more event sourced way to make it easier to provide diff-sets of changes in the source API data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such tool. I'm not sure such a tool will exist, because

1. retrieving data from GraphQL requires only the thinnest of layers over the existing GraphQL libraries, which are quite feature-rich
2. the transformation/writing will likely be part of a different tool. I'm sure several tools for this already exist. The simplest example I could think of is Git. Getting a diff is as simple as running `git diff` after overwriting an existing version-controlled file.

A simple example of retrieving the data is adapted from the [`graphql-request` Documentation Quickstart](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/blob/e4b3932c927ed9c04c89b488f35e6f0b654536d7/README.md#quickstart)

```
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'

const query = gql`
  {
    Movie(title: "Inception") {
      releaseDate
      actors {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

request('https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/movies', query)
  .then((data) => writeFile('data.json', data))
```

Comment: yes, actual query will be simple, I was more after something to take care of smart queuing, error handling, etc

Comment: the data set is 500.000 rows and quite a few GB's uncompressed, so this is the library i'm looking for. it cant just fetch all and assume it will work in one go

Comment: Understood. Again I don't know of such a tool, but maybe one does exist. Otherwise implementing pagination is fairly trivial, but you'll need a storage strategy -- split the results into different files or merge them. I don't know what your data source is, but maybe there is a full dataset available for raw download? That might simplify things. Good luck